# How does tab-completion "know" what files there are in sub/super folder?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, tab-completion

I wonder how tab-completion knows that certain file exists in a directory above the current directory or in the working directory?

If I have a file named `foobar` in a subdirectory and I type in `foo` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> afterwards in a Linux (or Mac OS) terminal the terminal instantly knows it's there, even tough the file may just be created by a program.

Is there some sort of index table that constantly keeps track of which files/folders exist in which the terminal looks the completion up?
How does this work?

Comment: "some sort of index table that constantly keeps track of which files/folders exist" ... yes, it's called the filesystem. It keeps track of which files & folders exist. But you probably already knew that; it seems like you're asking something else, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: No, I'm not asking something else. Sorry for my lack of clarity. I just wonder what happens step by step when I use tab-complete. If it reads the filesystem, does this mean that tab-completion works differently (in terms of speed) based on which filesystem is used (NTFS, HFS, etc...)?

Answer (score 3):

The moment you start tab-completion, it will scan the directory for files.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what `scan` exactly means? Does it open the folder and sort of greps through the file list? Or is it more sophisticated than that? And does this mean tab-completions becomes slower when the amount of files grows and that it's dependent on which letter the tab-completions starts?

Comment: @BartArondson more or less, it reads the list of files in the directory. Yes, it'll be slower the more files there are. Yes, it'll be slower on slower filesystems (try it over a network filesystem over the Internet sometime, and be prepared to wait).

Comment: It uses glob to find files and directories. Yes, more files means slower results.